# About Vim and Mark Plugin

Tags: vim, gvim

There is a nice plugin [Mark](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666) which can highlight multiple words.

Mark's default defined colors are just six.
According to the document, we can add any color which we want.

```
highlight def MarkWord1  ctermbg=Cyan     ctermfg=Black  guibg=#8CCBEA    guifg=Black
highlight def MarkWord2  ctermbg=Green    ctermfg=Black  guibg=#A4E57E    guifg=Black
highlight def MarkWord3  ctermbg=Yellow   ctermfg=Black  guibg=#FFDB72    guifg=Black
highlight def MarkWord4  ctermbg=Red      ctermfg=Black  guibg=#FF7272    guifg=Black
highlight def MarkWord5  ctermbg=Magenta  ctermfg=Black  guibg=#FFB3FF    guifg=Black
highlight def MarkWord6  ctermbg=Blue     ctermfg=Black  guibg=#9999FF    guifg=Black
highlight def MarkWord7  ctermbg=DarkCyan      ctermfg=Black  guibg=#008B8B      guifg=Black
highlight def MarkWord8  ctermbg=DarkRed      ctermfg=Black  guibg=#800000      guifg=Black
highlight def MarkWord9  ctermbg=DarkGreen      ctermfg=Black  guibg=#254117       guifg=Black
highlight def MarkWord10  ctermbg=Gray       ctermfg=Black  guibg=#2f4f4f    guifg=Black
highlight def MarkWord11  ctermbg=DarkGray       ctermfg=Black  guibg=#A9A9A9    guifg=Black
```

I was able to add 5 colors. -I wanted to add 20 colors.
But whenever I add some common color(eg, Purple), the mark script complains "I don't know the color"
It's annoying me.

What colors are allowed the script?
If you had, let me know yours please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the list of available colors in gVim do

```
help gui-colors
```

To see the list of terminal colors (although this varies somewhat) see

```
help cterm-colors
```

This of course goes for colors that have a name. You can always define them in #AAAAAA form, in which case, you're only restricted by the amount of colors your environment supports.